# How to assert exception using django.test.TestCase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unit-testing, exception

I am using Django 3 (latest) and tried to assert exception using `unittest` `assertRaises` as in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#exceptions).

My code is raising `django.template.TemplateSyntaxError` when it gets an `IndexError`:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()
@register.tag(name="autopaginate")
def do_autopaginate(parser, token):
    split = token.split_contents()
    as_index = None
    context_var = None
    for i, bit in enumerate(split):
        if bit == "as":
            as_index = i
            break
    if as_index is not None:
        try:
            context_var = split[as_index + 1]
        except IndexError:
            raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
                (
                    f"Context variable assignment "
                    f"must take the form of {{% {split[0]} object.example_set.all ... as "
                    f"context_var_name %}}"
                )
            )
        del split[as_index : as_index + 2]
    if len(split) == 2:
        return AutoPaginateNode(split[1])
    if len(split) == 3:
        return AutoPaginateNode(split[1], paginate_by=split[2], context_var=context_var)
    if len(split) == 4:
        try:
            orphans = int(split[3])
        except ValueError:
            raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(f"Got {split[3]}, but expected integer.")
        return AutoPaginateNode(
            split[1], paginate_by=split[2], orphans=orphans, context_var=context_var
        )
    raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
        f"{split[0]} tag takes one required argument and one optional argument"
    )
```

My test code following documentation is:

```py
from django import template
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.test import TestCase

class TestHttpRequest(HttpRequest):
    __test__ = False
    page = 1

class TestTemplatePaginateTags(TestCase):
    def test_render_range_by_var_as_index_error(self):
        t = template.Template(
            "{% load pagination_tags %}{% autopaginate var by as %}{{ foo }}"
        )
        c = template.Context({"var": range(21), "request": TestHttpRequest()})
        with self.assertRaises(template.TemplateSyntaxError):
            t.render(c)
```

Full code is in [this PR](https://github.com/staticdev/django-pagination-bootstrap/pull/110).

Unfortunately, instead of passing the test it is failing saying that it is throwing the exception:

> FAILED
> tests/test_pagination_tags.py::TestTemplatePaginateTags::test_render_range_by_var_as_index_error
>
> - django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Context variable assignment must take the form of {% autopaginate
>   object.example_set.all ... as context_var_name %}

This is exactly what I expect to make this test pass. I don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error will be raised when you *construct* the `Template` object, *not* when you render it. You thus expect the error to raise with `t.render(c)`, but the error is in the `t = template.Template(…)`, so you need to wrap another statement in the context manager:

```
class TestTemplatePaginateTags(TestCase):
    def test_render_range_by_var_as_index_error(self):
        with self.assertRaises(template.TemplateSyntaxError):
            template.Template(
                "{% load pagination_tags %}{% autopaginate var by as %}{{ foo }}"
            )
```